# Showtime series "The Tudors" casting question

Tags: casting, the-tudors

Just finished watching the complete Showtime series "The Tudors".  I very much enjoyed the show.  One of my complaints is the actor whom played Henry VIII.

I am not discrediting the young man's abilities as an actor.  The main problem is that he does not resemble King Henry VIII at all.

Does anybody have a source or know why that actor was cast for this role?

Comment: Mostly because people enjoy watching "pretty" people better. A Henry VIII -ish actor would have discouraged viewership.

Comment: A google search for young henry the 8th shows he does have a bit of a resemblance.

Comment: @wbogacz is correct.  The show contains an abundance of sex and nudity.  Viewers would be discouraged from watching the show if Henry was portrayed in an exact likeness.  John Rhys-Meyers did a great job, even if he does not physically resemble King Henry....which is a compliment to the actor :)

Comment: @wbogacz - Young Henry VIII was described by his contemporaries as a very handsome man. It wasn't until later that he became the fat king most people know from his portraits

Comment: @SystemDown while young Henry was described by his contemporaries as handsome in his youth, there is still little to no resemblance to John Rhys-Meyers, even in Henry's youth.

Comment: @SystemDown - Prince, then King - who would dare to NOT call him handsome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creator Michael Hirst explains his choice to cast Jonathan Rhys-Meyers as Henry VIII.

> We felt that Johnny captured the essence of Henry.  He portrays Henry in a way that shows him as a man while also displaying a regal quality.  Which of course you need to portray Henry VIII.

Actor Jonathan Rhys-Meyers on his role as Henry VIII:

> I understand that I do not look like Henry, but I have completely immersed myself into this character.  I hope my hard work will show through my performance and that people will overlook the physical differences between Henry and myself.

I own the box set of "The Tudors" which includes bonus features.  The above quotes are from interviews conducted with the show creator Michael Hirst and actor Jonathan Rhys-Meyers.